# How to raise events based on annotations

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

We currently have a couple of microservices written using spring + java/kotlin and as much as everything is running pretty well we have an ongoing problem, for almost every change in the entities we need to send rather a created or updated entity event, at first to achieve that we simply wrote a component that sends the event, for instance if someone updates an user in your application after the save/update we call

`userEventComponent.sendUpdate(updatedUser)`

but the amount of repetition in the code is growing exponentially, which leads me to the title question is there a way to simply annotate a method to always publish an event with the updated user?

eg:

```
@SendUpdateEvent("example annotation")
@Transactional
fun update(id: UUID): User {
 //code
}
```

Comment: So, basically aspects? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop

Comment: If you are using some ORM that supports Entity listeners, you could add a `@EntityListener` to your entity and then using the `@PostPersist` or `@PostUpdate` annotations you can do an action after the entity has been saved.